# Xcode upload distribution

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect

I have tried to upload the updated app through the latest Xcode. Yet, I forgot to create a new version at iTunes Connect before the upload. And then Xcode shows that the upload is successful. However, I cannot see my upload at iTunes Connect. I cannot upload again as it says already exists. I wonder how can I link up the uploaded binary with the app on iTunes connect and submit to Apple.

Comment: On YourApp/Testflight/Testflight Builds/See all builds, it doesn't appear in process?

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you create a new version in iTunes connect and then select your uploaded load at the 'build' section?

You can only upload the same version of binaries for one time.

There is a tab named 'Activity' inside Any of your application management page and you should be able to see all your uploaded histories.

Answer (score 0):

It was problem of the server at that time. Now it is solved. thanks :)